# Why cant opened downloaded docx files ,in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, download, content-type

I try to download a docx file from serverside.
What is my wrong ?

this is code :

```
 FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filepath);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = " + ((Button)sender).CommandName + ".docx");
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();
```

Comment: Is this a normal asp.net file and which browser are you using? Is it happening on different browsers?

Comment: I download it but it doesnt open in office , and i use chrome

Comment: It's difficult to tell what could be wrong as a glance. Docx files are just zip files so you could rename the file to a zip file and see if it opens. If you are running this code in normal asp.net then it's likely that there are some funnies cropping up with what .NET adds to the response which is why I suggested the ashx handler below. That depends a lot on which event in ASP.NET you are running the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted something similar in another question for an PDF but here goes. It's much easier to stream this sort of data back through an ASHX handler.

Something like what I posted in this question but with a docx file.

[Display PDF in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603277/display-pdf-in-iframe/11603354#11603354)

It looks like you are using a normal ASP.NET page and are trying to modify the standard behavior by clearing out the headers, etc. You won't have to fiddle with the headers or anything like that with an ashx handler.