# ASP.NET Display PDF Document with close button

Tags: asp.net, ipad, pdf

I have a very simple web site that takes two parameters and then displays a PDF document from our file server.  Using Response.WriteFile I can get the PDF to open in a new page on an iPad.

Since my web app is running fullscreen on the iPad the PDF opens fullscreen and there is no way for the user to close the PDF without hitting the home button and opening up the app again.  I'd like to add a close button to the page that opens with PDF.

It is possible using frames in ASP.NET to display the PDF on one from and a close button in the other frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Display PDF in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603277/display-pdf-in-iframe)

Using the link above I was able to get the PDF displayed in an iframe and then I added a Close button that closes the page.