# dynamically displaying PDFs in C# MVC with iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, iframe, razor

I have a File button to search for a File. I want to take the selected Path and display it in an iframe.

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })
</div>
```

My current iframe is:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <iframe src="@Url.Action("GetPDF")" ; height="1000" ; width="1000";%>'></iframe>
```

My current (static) GetPDF Method is the following:

```
public FileStreamResult GetPDF()
{

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\Temp.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        return File(fs, "application/pdf");

}
```

So could you please help me and tell me how I can update my Iframe to the Pdf that i choose with my editor-field?

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? Where are the PDF's located, on the client machine or on the server? My assumption is you are trying to display a preview of the PDF from the client machine? If so your solution will not work, as the `GetPDF` action will be trying to load the PDF from server side.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is already an answer to your question and it is as follows:
[Display PDF in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603277/display-pdf-in-iframe)

**EDIT 1:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetPdf(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedPdf)
    {
        // user has selected a file
        if (uploadedPdf!= null && uploadedPdf.ContentLength > 0) 
        {
           //you have the file stream here *uploadedPdf*

            return File(fs, "application/pdf");
        }

        return null;      
    }
```

In order to achieve async file upload you can look into 
[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object) or [jQueryForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api) and attach an event on the file input.

**EDIT 2:**
easy way to get from stream to byte array

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
    byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
}
```

Comment: thx, but this doesnt help me much, because I am unable to get my path:<div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })
        </div>